# CGRectApplyAffineTransform then CGAffineTransformInvert doesn't return to original position

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgaffinetransform

This does not seem possible and I'm sure there's a simple solution but I cannot work it out.  My High School matrix math is a bit rusty :)

I'm building a `CGAffineTransform` to do translation-rotation-translation of a `CGRect` and then trying to use the inverse [CGAffineTransformInvert](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000946-CH1g-F16979) to return to the original location. But it doesn't.  I've managed to reduce it to this:

```
//  start building the transform...
//  translate so (0,0) is at centre of image
CGAffineTransform affine = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-100, -100);

//  add a rotate
affine = CGAffineTransformConcat(affine, CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/4));

//  get the inverse
CGAffineTransform inverseAffine = CGAffineTransformInvert(affine);

//  now test this: pick a starting CGRect
CGRect start = CGRectMake(50, 40, 10, 20);

// use my CGAffineTransform to move "start" to "midpoint"
CGRect midpoint = CGRectApplyAffineTransform(start, affine);

//  use the inverse to move "midpoint" to "finish"
CGRect finish = CGRectApplyAffineTransform(midpoint, inverseAffine);

//  what did we get
NSLog(@"start    %5.1f %5.1f %5.1f %5.1f", start.origin.x, start.origin.y, start.size.width, start.size.height);
NSLog(@"midpoint %5.1f %5.1f %5.1f %5.1f", midpoint.origin.x, midpoint.origin.y, midpoint.size.width, midpoint.size.height);
NSLog(@"finish   %5.1f %5.1f %5.1f %5.1f", finish.origin.x, finish.origin.y, finish.size.width, finish.size.height);
```

The output looks like this:

```
2011-09-29 ... start     50.0  40.0  10.0  20.0
2011-09-29 ... midpoint  -7.1 -77.8  21.2  21.2
2011-09-29 ... finish    40.0  35.0  30.0  30.0
```

Shouldn't the finish rect be the same as the start?  Isn't that what `CGAffineTransformInvert` is supposed to do?

If I do the same thing but with a `CGPoint` instead of a `CGRect` it seems to work ok.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK I found my mistake.

> [Because affine transforms do not preserve rectangles in general, the function CGRectApplyAffineTransform returns the smallest rectangle that contains the transformed corner points of the rect parameter](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000946-CH1g-BBCGEBEH)

not some strange twisted non-CGRect-ish thing.

Answer (score 7):

Copied from [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_affine/dq_affine.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH204-SW1): 
*You can operate on a `CGRect` structure by calling the function `CGRectApplyAffineTransform`. This function returns the smallest rectangle that contains the transformed corner points of the rectangle passed to it. If the affine transform that operates on the rectangle performs **only scaling and translation operations**, the returned rectangle coincides with the rectangle constructed from the four transformed corners.*

Comment: You will see that I had already discovered that solution but thanks for reminding me to accept it!